# Are there ferries or boats I can take between Kinmen and Matsu or between Kinmen and the main island of Taiwan?

Tags: ferries, taiwan, sea-travel, islands

On a previous trip I took a ferry from mainland China (PRC) to Matsu, an island controlled by Taiwan but close to the PRC and then another ferry from Matsu to Keelung, on the main island of Taiwan.

I know that Matsu has a sister island called Kinmen. Also known as Quemoy.

I can find that there are ferries mainland China and Kinmen, but I can't seem to verify one way or another if there's any way to pay for a passage either between Kinmen and Matsu, or between Kinmen and the main island of Taiwan.

Can anybody verify that such ferries definitely do or definitely do not operate. Or if there's another known way for tourists to travel by any other kind of affordable boat on either route?

---

It seems that I have made an incorrect assumption that these two islands are near each other, but they seem not to be after all. Matsu is off the coast of Fuzhou, whereas Kinmen is off the coast of Xiamen. They are in fact about 250 km or 155 mi apart!

Still, this makes me wonder about any island-hopping possibilities as there's also a bunch of islands controlled by the PRC that I know even less about.

Answer (score 4):

Here you can see the real time schedule:

http://kinmen.altervista.org/orario_traghetti_kinmen-cina_popolare

It is from an Italian website but the info is in English and Mandarin.

Summary:

There are ferries from / to Kinmen 金門 to / from Mainland China (五通 WuTong + Dōngdù 东渡 in Xiamen & 泉州 QuanZhou) Occasionally there are ferries connecting Kinmen to Taiwan too, but it's much faster and practical to take a flight in that case. There are commercial boats on that route, but I don't think they are allowed to carry passengers. Anyway it can be dangerous. That's it.

Comment: Could you quote the relevant parts? It doesn't help future users if the site goes down or the link changes :/

Comment: I don't care about fast or practical (-: